# Angular ui-grid 'grid menu' scrolls when toggling columns while enableFilter: true

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to upgrade from ui-grid 3.0.1 to latest stable (currently 3.0.7), but I'm seeing this strange behavior of the grid menu in all versions greater than 3.0.1:

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UQ6Jeh6acfEGZliKgsI8?p=preview

First, open the grid menu, then scroll down a bit and toggle one of the columns. You'll notice it automatically scrolls you to the top of the list again, making it more difficult to toggle other columns.

Second, open app.js and change enableFiltering to false:

```
enableFiltering: false
```

Refresh and try toggling columns in the grid menu again. It maintains the scroll position, making it easier to toggle the rest of the columns quickly.

This was never the case with 3.0.1. Does anyone know how I can get the latest builds to play nicely with this filtering enabled?

Comment: There are only 2 rows in the data of your plunker. Makes it hard to scroll down. What do you mean by "toggle a column"?

Comment: You shouldn't need any more data than that to see the behavior. It's the grid MENU that scrolls. Open the grid menu (the 'hamburger menu' on the top right) - then scroll and toggle some columns. You'll see it jumps you back to the top of the menu.

Comment: "Toggle a column" just means switch them between visible/invisible.

Comment: Same problem - others are having this issue too - there are a few open bugs in their github - I added one